# windows phone supported capturing formats

Tags: windows-phone, pcm, audio-capture

I'm working on a project for windows phone and I need to encode PCM to G.711.So I need device to capture audio with these features: 16 bits, 8000 sample/s.

capturesource.AudioCaptureDevice.SupportedFormats

returns a list of different supported capture formats.When I run a Silverlight app on my pc this code returns 10 different formats which include the mentioned format I need.However as I use the code for windows phone app and I run it on windows emulator it only returns 6 format which doesn't include appropriate format for my purpose.
But my questions are:

Is the presented supportedformats property using windows phone emulator is as same as that of real windows phone device or it can be different?

Is there a way to change the capturing features of device?

Comment: Good question. It seems my phone doesn't return a mono (1-track) format.

Comment: @LéonPelletier: Recently I encountered the same problem in native c++ using WASAPI.After searching the web for the solution I noticed it seems many devices only support  48KHz and 32 bit sample depth and developer should resample it if they want different sample rate.I found some API in this area including:libsamplerate and libsndfile.